# How to load 10 levels assigned to 10 buttons in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, simplejson, jsonnode

How to load list object Data in Unity?
I want 10 levels assigned to 10 buttons.
I think use jsonNode.
Hope everybody helps, please.

I don't want to do it like this. Does anyone have a faster way?

```
[Serializable]
public class LoadLevel{
   public Level level1
   public Level level2
   public Level level3
...
}
```

My data file looks like this:

```
{
   "level1": {
        "LevelHeight": 320,
        "Stars": [],
        "LevelID": 85,
        "LevelTime": 90,
        "LevelWidth": 820
    },
   "level2": {
        "LevelHeight": 320,
        "Stars": [],
        "LevelID": 88,
        "LevelTime": 90,
        "LevelWidth": 1170
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array? However, `Does anyone have a faster way?` .. faster regarding what?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data to array, and get level by index in array with the same index of array buttons.

Comment: how to load list objects, without using arrays. do you know?